# How to dynamically add PEM certificate from ConfigMap to Java cacerts in OpenShift?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

We are trying to build a set of the same services, which are connected to different MQTT Brokers and different 3rd party Systems. Each service needs to have it's own certificate to be able to connect to it's own MQTT Broker.

To do so, we are using one Jenkins pipeline, which is pushing newly build Docker image to multiple target projects in OpenShift. Each project has it's own ConfigMap with connection/configuration details.

Now the problem is that we would like to do the same to PEM Certificates. Easiest and working way is to keep certs on repository, and import those in dockerfile. It's working fine, but it is not scaling up, when we want to add more PODs in OpenShift with same service, but different configurations.

To do it dynamically we thought about *initContainers*. This would allow us to send cert dynamically.

```
initContainers:
  - name: inject-pem-to-cacerts
    image: <imageName>
    env:
      - name: MQTT_CERT_PEM
        value: home/fromMount/cert.pem
     - name: CACERTS
       value: $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts 
    command: ['/bin/bash']
    args: ['-c', "keytool -import -noprompt -keystore $CACERTS -file $MQTT_CERT_PEM -storepass changeit -alias service-$MQTT_CERT_PEM"]
```

In that case we are recieving *PermissionDenied* on that specific path. Sudo is not an option here as far as we tested. Maybe it's a matter of security context in YAML, but don't know what should be set.

If there is other way to do it better I would love to listen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing stems from the fact that Init-Containers are **not** the right tool here. Init-Containers are started **before** the Pod containers, therefore the truststore you configure here, is going to be on the Init-Container and **not** on the application container. To achieve what you are trying to do, I recommend the [PostStart Container Lifecycle Handler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/):

```
  containers:
    - name: my-container
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec: ['-c', "keytool -import -noprompt -keystore $CACERTS -file $MQTT_CERT_PEM -storepass changeit -alias service-$MQTT_CERT_PEM"]
```

Taking a step back, I wonder about one alternative solution. If I understood correctly, you need to install the cacerts for the server certs of the various MQTT brokers. So, since cacerts are **not confidential**, why not work with a singular Docker image that has **all cacerts** installed on them. That would take away a lot of complexity from K8s.

Comment: The case is that we are adding more pods at some point with same app, but connecting to new brokers on different servers. In that case, I would be force to restart ALL already existing pods to pull new image with all certs, right? That's exactly what I want to avoid. Nevertless thanks for this postStart. Looks promising.

Comment: Regarding restarting, the postStart approach should not differ from the Docker image approach. If your app needs a new certificate, you will have to restart the Pod be it to pull a new image or to trigger the postStart lifecycle handler. Also, if you plan for individual postStart configurations for you apps, they will have to be deployed in separate k8s deployments.

Comment: Have you found another solution?